# Linq join on guid and string

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 tables 1 legacy members table that has a guid member id and a new groups table that has a string for the guid

I want to join these tables using linq but I am having problems with the join

q = a guid string

```
var member = (from m in db.Members 
              join g in db.Groups 
              on m.memberid equals g.UserId 
              where g.GroupId == q 
              select new { id = g.UserId, name = m.firstname + " " + m.lastname }
              ).ToList();
```

The above fails on compile trying to compare the memberid with the userid

And this returns no values

```
var member = (from m in db.Members.ToList() 
              join g in db.Groups 
              on m.memberid.ToString() equals g.UserId 
              where g.GroupId == q 
              select new { id = g.UserId, name = m.firstname + " " + m.lastname }
              ).ToList();
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Mostly, you should read the compiler warning, because it will tell you what you're doing wrong. Is `memberId` really the name of m's property? have you tried using `==` rather than 'equals`?

Comment: What exact error do you get?

Comment: Can you share the models for Members and Groups? 

@Magus `==` is not how you do a linq join. You have to use `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, I'm guessing your `memberid` is a `Guid` and `UserId` is a `string` that's why it gives you a compile error.

The second one, I'm guessing your `UserId` doesn't really match the `memberid` value that it was given. Double check that the `UserId` from the Legacy database or whichever it is, is actually matching a `Guid` value. It probably don't have `-` in it and it is trying to compare it, which won't match.

Comment: Also I would have to add that even IF you manage to get this query to work, you will get appalling performance. This is because the conversion of Guid to string will not be indexed, so each query will require a table scan over the Member table. Better fix the schema.